# Preserve CASE WHEN output as new column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, case

I am new to MySQL and this question may look silly, but:

I have a `dogs` table and I categorize their size by their weight:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN weight < 15 THEN 'Small'
        WHEN weight < 40 THEN 'Medium'
        ELSE 'Big'
    END AS Size
FROM dogs;
```

This outputs my table with a new column `Size` at the end.
And I would like to permanently append that column to this table so it's visible when I use `SELECT * FROM dogs;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
ALTER TABLE dogs
ADD COLUMN Size VARCHAR(6) AS (CASE WHEN weight < 15 THEN 'Small'
                                    WHEN weight < 40 THEN 'Medium'
                                    ELSE 'Big' END) VIRTUAL
```

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)